# Choose the satellites used in GPS fix with Android

Tags: android, gps

I am working on GPS relative positionning and I would like to use Android phones for this purpose. Therefore, if I want two phones to get a good accuracy on their relative positions, I need them to compute their GPS positions from the same satellites (so they will share the same error).

Is there a way to choose which satellites are going to be used in order to compute the GPS position with Android ?

Or maybe, is there a way to manually compute the GPS position using the data from the satellites that are provided by the Android API ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to choose which satellites are going to be used in order to compute the GPS position with Android ?

AFAIK there is none, you are at the mercy of the proprietary of the chipset algorithm for node selection. You can't really tell the chipset to use which node to compute its solution.

> I need them to compute their GPS positions from the same satellites (so they will share the same error).

You can choose to pick or to drop the data if the solution they produce nearly identical by checking their NMEA sentences. Specifically look for GGA and GSA sentence. GGA contains the fix quality and GSA contains the nodes being used for the solution.

You can compare the [PRN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GPS_signals#Coarse.2FAcquisition_code) to find out which nodes being used for the solution and better yet you can also add some [DOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dilution_of_precision_%28GPS%29) comparation for additional filter whether to use the data or to drop the data for your computation.

> if I want two phones to get a good accuracy on their relative positions

But beware, this is the primary reason that your task will be difficult because the visible nodes will become relative to their position. Even if your units are close enough to each other, there are no telling that all of them will pick the identical nodes for their solution.

> Or maybe, is there a way to manually compute the GPS position using the data from the satellites that are provided by the Android API ?

lastly for acquiring the NMEA from Android API, you should register an [nmea listener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#addNmeaListener%28android.location.GpsStatus.NmeaListener%29) and start listening by calling [requestLocationUpdates](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates%28long,%20float,%20android.location.Criteria,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29)